# Can't increment field in interface

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have an array of objects (interfaces).

After this array is created, with objects, I need to increment a value
inside each object. ('x1' to 'x2').

At the end of the iteration, all the 'x1' and 'x2' values are the latest value of index.

```
let data: any = [];

let object: any = {
    xaxis: null,
    yaxis: null,
}

data.push(object)
data.push(object)

const doTHIS = () => {

    const newData = data.map((item: any, index: any) => {
        item.xaxis = 'x' + index + 1;
        item.yaxis = 'y' + index + 1;
        return item
    });
    return newData;
}
```

Expected results:

```
[ { xaxis: 'x1', yaxis: 'y1' }, { xaxis: 'x2', yaxis: 'y2' } ]
```

Actual Results:

```
[ { xaxis: 'x2', yaxis: 'y2' }, { xaxis: 'x2', yaxis: 'y2' } ]
```

Comment: You have the same object twice in the `data` array.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Comparing_Objects: "objects are a reference type".

Comment: You push the same object twice into the Array. All indices in that array point to the same Object, therefore every change in your loop is done to the very same object.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're pushing the same object reference at both place of array so changes at reference reflecting at both places, you need to add a copy ( i am creating a shallow copy using [`...spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) )

since associativity is left to right ( [`+ operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table) ) so if you use `x + index + 1` you will get values like `x01` and `x11` , if you need value like `x1` and `x2` you need to use `x + ( index + 1 )`

```js
let data = [];

let object = {
  xaxis: null,
  yaxis: null,
}

data.push({...object})
data.push({...object})

const doThis = () => {
  const newData = data.map((item, index) => {
    item.xaxis = 'x' + (index + 1);
    item.yaxis = 'y' + (index + 1);
    return item
  });
  return newData;
}

console.log(doThis())
```

***On side note*** :- use camelCase `doThis` instead of `doTHIS`

Answer (score 0):

You push the same object twice into the Array.

All indices in that array point to the same Object (`data[0] === data[1]`), therefore every change in your loop is done to the very same object.

Telling by your code, it seems to me that you're rather new to programming. I think what you wanted to do is this:

```
let data = Array.from({ length: 2 }, (,index) => { //we don't need the first argument here
  return {
    xaxis: 'x' + (index + 1),
    yaxis: 'y' + (index + 1),
  };
});

console.log(data);
```